# Is it possible to check which video/audio `codec` supported by which browser using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, codec

More precisely, I would like to check which codecs I can use in a browser for video/audio elements in HTML5. (e.g. Safari supports H.264, but I also would like to know which codecs I can use)

Since specification changes over-time I would like to do it somehow automaticaly, not based on browser-codec tables.

I think, it can be written as a function in JS(if it is not written, yet). I have tried to Google it, but wasn't even close to find an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reference link  : https://www.nomensa.com/blog/2011/detecting-browser-compatibility-html5-video-and-audio
You can do something like this :

```js
// Define the get_mime function
var get_mime = function(filetype) {
  var mimetype = '';
  var media_container = 'video';
  switch (filetype) {
    case 'mp4':
      mimetype = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"';
      break;
    case 'ogg':
      mimetype = 'video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"';
      break;
    case 'webm':
      mimetype = 'video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"';
      break;
    case 'mp3':
      mimetype = 'audio/mpeg';
      media_container = 'audio';
      break;
  }
  return {
    'mimetype': mimetype,
    'container': media_container
  };
};

// Check to see if the browser can render the file type
// using HTML5
var supports_media = function(mimetype, container) {
  var elem = document.createElement(container);
  if (typeof elem.canPlayType == ‘ function’) {
    var playable = elem.canPlayType(mimetype);
    if ((playable.toLowerCase() == 'maybe') || (playable.toLowerCase() == 'probably')) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};

// When the DOM has loaded check the file extension of each media link
// and serve up appropriate media player
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(‘a.youtube - links’).each(function() {
    var path = $(this).attr(‘href’);
    var extension = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    var extension_info = get_mime(extension);
    if (supports_media(extension_info.mimetype, extension_info.container)) {
      // Serve up an HTML5 Media Player and controls
      serve_html5();
    } else {
      // Serve up a flash based video for browsers that
      //will not play the file using HTML5
      serve_flash();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: If you are going to copy something from a website verbatim, you should provide an attribution, and link to the source

Comment: Well, didn't mind the attribution, but I didn't remember the site, I have copied and used that in my project, copied the same from the project and placed it here. will try to get the link and put it here.

Comment: [Possibly this](https://www.nomensa.com/blog/2011/detecting-browser-compatibility-html5-video-and-audio)? We're waiting, the mouse pointer on the flag link ...

Comment: @PatrickEvans, I agree with you that it is a duplicated question(as I mentioned I didn't find an answer), but is it possible to somehow auto-update supported codecs ? To not do a hard-code as in an aswer and in a post you have linked.