# How to check whether a media type is supported by my browser?

Tags: javascript, html

I am giving the functionality to the users of uploading videos . After they upload the video i grab the video from the file input tag using the following code

```
document.getElementById(
      "video_file_chooser"
    ).files[0];
```

And Now I want to play this video . Now I have no filters , hence a user can upload any format (eg:mp4,avi etc). **What I want to do is to check that whether the uploaded format is supported by my browser (can be played) or not** ? Can I do this with the help of js?Thanks for the help

Comment: [HTMLMediaElement.canPlayType()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canPlayType) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to check which video/audio \`codec\` supported by which browser using JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393784/is-it-possible-to-check-which-video-audio-codec-supported-by-which-browser-usi)

Comment: HTMLMediaElement.canPlayType is not a function

Answer (score 4):

You can use following code:

```js
var obj = document.createElement('video');
console.log(obj.canPlayType('video/mp4'));
```

There are three possibilities which can occur:

1. `probably`: The specified media type appears to be playable.
2. `maybe`: Cannot tell if the media type is playable without playing it.
3. `'' (empty string)`: The specified media type definitely cannot be played.